# svn to build a zip file when commiting

Tags: perl, svn, bash

I have a Joomla project based in SVN.

Problem is every time I change some file and commit I need to update package as well and ftp to live server.

How to automate this process?

Problem is that project has 2 directories in Joomla:

administrator/components/...
components/...

Thank you

Comment: Write a shell script that goes through the same sequence of commands that you would follow to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at doing a "[svn hook](http://www.google.com/search?q=svn%20hook)" or "[svn hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=snv%20hook&submit=search)", some of the website deploy hooks are pretty great examples.

Answer (score 0):

"Post-commit hook" namely. If you can do this operations by hand (in command prompt in non-interactive mode), you can write these action into script (*sh or cmd)